# admin account not getting created in MacOS high sierra

Tags: macos

I am using macOS high Sierra. By mistake I converted my admin account to standard user account. Now by entering into the single user mode and trying to mount the disk,it shows message that "devise is write locked "  and "IO failed , error = 13" and trying to remove the apple set up done file the error message is "no such file found."  Please guide how to resolve this situation.

Answer (score -1):

What were you doing when you "converted" the account type?  There is no need to re-run the setup.  Just toggle the checkbox in System Preferences > Users and Groups > Allow user to administer this computer.

Comment: You can only do that if there is an administrator to authorise it... otherwise what would be the point of having a standard user?

Comment: So your interpretation of this problem is that there was a single Admin account and the user somehow converted it to Standard?  That's not supposed to be possible but I never tried.

Comment: It's done often enough, which is presumably why the OP was attempting the 'applesetupdone' trick - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=applesetupdone